# Applying slots, one after another for a list

Tags: list-manipulation, slot

For this function:

```
Fun[x_] := 3 x^3 + 4 x^2 - 2 x - 1
```

I apply Map:

```
D[Fun[x], {x, #}] & /@ Range@3
```

and I get this polynomial list:

```
{-2 + 8 x + 9 x^2, 8 + 18 x, 18}
```

Now I wanna plug ***x*** into a numeric value (for example: x=1) and I get a numeric list like this (x=1):

```
{15, 26, 18}
```

How do I get this? Thanks in advance

Comment: see [ReplaceAll (/.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) in the docs. `D[Fun[x], {x, #}] & /@ Range@3 /. x -> 1`   or `D[Fun[x], {x, #}] /. x -> 1 & /@ Range@3 `

Comment: Seriously, I'm newbie, thanks a lot...

Comment: Consider instead `Table[Derivative[k][Fun][1], {k, 3}]`.